# Listview item swipe right open new screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, navigation, snapchat

How to open new screen by swiping to the right of `listview` item similar to as `snapchat` app. This is the video link that i want to achieve this.
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTYZUF7OEes)

I tried to check with listview slidable but there is no option for navigating to new screen.
Below is the sample dart code of two screens. By swiping right of `listview` item i want to open `TestPage.dart` screen. How to achieve this in Flutter?

> FirstPage.dart

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      ClipOval(
                        child: Image.network(
                          'https://googleflutter.com/sample_image.jpg',
                          width: 50,
                          height: 50,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            right: 10.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment:
                              MainAxisAlignment
                                  .spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  'Person 1',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const FittedBox(
                                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'last seen at 8:22 PM'
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 5.0),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                    .size
                                    .width *
                                    0.50,
                                child:Text('test'),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),],),],),);}),
```

> TestPage.dart

```
    class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if snap chat is built with flutter but that new page looks like a drawer. As for the sliding list item, take a look at this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable

Comment: @Eric I tried this but doesn't work

Comment: Snapchat uses bottomNavigation view. In flutter, if you implement bottom navigation view with page views in it, you can too swipe right n left too out of the box

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin Inside GestureDetector there is onPanUpdate i can able to swipe but now new problem is when i swipe to right a little bit then it navigates to second page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Dismissible widget like this:

```
ListView.builder(itemBuilder: ((context, index) => Dismissible(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  child: ListTile(),
  direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
  onDismissed: (DismissDirection dismissDirection){
    Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft, child: DetailScreen()));
  },

)
)
);
```

Comment: As mentioned in youtube video, if i slide the tile then i can able to see some portion of new page. But here if i dismiss completely then only i can able to view the new page.

Comment: Then should you be able to slide the navigated page to get back?

Comment: If no there is a cool package named PageTransition:          https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition

Comment: You can use it instead of material page route or you can make a manual page transition. Here are examples: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation